# "Post an Adaptive card to a teams channel and wait for a response" error in azure logic app designer

Tags: azure, logic

[image][image: here is error image]

I am doing this task from github: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-ad-conditional-access-apis/tree/main/02-test

I have copied JSON from Logic app code viewer as in the screenshot above:

Comment: The error message is telling you quite clearly that there is an error in the JSON of the adaptive card. Without seeing the JSON I can't comment any further, try posting your JSON into [here](https://jsonlint.com/) to see what validation errors are picked up. You could also try pasting it into the designer [here](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/) (make sure you select Microsoft Teams from the dropdown).

Comment: from 1st link, JSON is valid

Comment: but pasting that same JSON in 2nd link produces empty adaptive card !

Comment: Mind pasting the JSON that you're using for the adaptive card into your question.

Comment: where to find that JSON?  i could find only this JSON from Azure portal